# How to handle Simple Data Processing in build()

Tags: flutter

In the [Performing Best Practices](https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/rendering/best-practices), it says under **Controlling build() cost**

> Avoid repetitive and costly work in `build()` methods since `build()` can be invoked frequently when ancestor Widgets rebuild.

I have two questions:

- Where should simple data processing happend if not `build`?
- How to prevent the data processing from repeating?

As as an example, when I say simple data processing, I mean, searching an array for certain elements and then mapping over those found values.

For reference, I understand that anything costly should end up in a `compute` resulting in a `Future` and then use `FutureBuilder`.

To avoid repetition for simple data processing would it be correct, to create a `StatefulWidget` to do the simple processing in the the `State` object and then somehow callback to build the widget tree with that data, sort of like

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return WidgetThatDoesDataProcessingBuilder(
    builder: (data) {
      return WidgetUsingData(data: data);
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Use a stateful widget also use a future builder then call a setState function when computation is complete to refresh the app state.

Comment: So it is correct to use a `StatefulWidget` to avoid repetition of simple data processing?

Comment: You tell me, would you rather restart the app just because you carried out a simple data process?

Comment: @samezedi That comment isn't helpful. I'm trying to figure out where data processing occurs. I understand for costly computations you can use FutureBuilder and compute, but what is the case for simple data processing. I got the impression that you are not suppose to put data processing in widgets as they should just react to state. So my question is, where does the data processing go?

Comment: The data processing goes inside the class